# Замена первой буквы в предложении на заглавную

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Всем доброе утро, столкнулась с проблемой замены первой строчной буквы в первом слове каждого предложения.
Мой код меняет все строчные буквы во всем предложении. Отношения с ассемблером не складываются, помогите пожалуйста.

```
.386 
.model flat, stdcall

includelib <c:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib>
includelib <c:\masm32\lib\user32.lib>

ExitProcess PROTO , :DWORD 
MessageBoxA PROTO , :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD

.data
caption db "MyPr", 0
message db "to be or not to be. there is the question.", 0

.code 
Winmain PROC
    lea esi, message

_proc:
    mov al, [esi]

    cmp al, 0
    jz _end

    cmp al, 'a'
    jna _next

    cmp al, 'z'
    jnb _next

    add BYTE PTR [esi], 'A' - 'a'

_next:
    inc esi
    jmp _proc


_end:   
    push 0
    push offset caption
    push offset message
    push 0
    call MessageBoxA

    push 0
    call ExitProcess

Winmain endp
end Winmain
```

Comment: Сформулируйте алгоритмически точно понятие "первая буква в первом слове предложения" (например, "первый не-пробел после пары символов точка-пробел"). Затем напишите поиск соответствующего символа в строке. А код капитализации уже есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решила вопрос, оказалось ничего сложного, просто не правильно ставила алгоритм перед собой.
вот код может кому понадобится:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
includelib Y:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib Y:\masm32\lib\user32.lib
ExitProcess PROTO ,:DWORD
MessageBoxA PROTO ,:DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD

.data
Caption db "Prog", 0
MyStr db "hi Emmy. how are you.", 0

.code
Winmain PROC
mov al, 'A' - 'a' ; 32
mov esi, offset MyStr ; lea esi, MyStr; в esi адрес MyStr
begin:
cmp BYTE PTR [esi], 0
jz exit
pr1:
cmp BYTE PTR [esi], 'a'
jae pr2
jmp point
pr2:
cmp BYTE PTR [esi], 'z'
jbe Up
jmp point
Up:
add BYTE PTR [esi], al
xor al, al
jmp break
point:
cmp BYTE PTR [esi], '.'
je ispoint
jmp break
ispoint:
mov al, 'A' - 'a'
break:
inc esi
jmp begin
exit:
push 0
push offset Caption
push offset MyStr
push 0
call MessageBoxA
push 0
call ExitProcess
Winmain endp
end Winmain
```